# CORB Job : Handle ServerConnectionException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, linux, bash, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I am trying to execute a CORB Job to process my documents. But it is throwing up the below exception after processing a part of the entire collection.

```
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Connection reset by peer
 [Session: user=<username>, cb={default} [ContentSource: <username>, cb={none} [provider: address=<xyz.com>/<IP>, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/7.0-2, Server: XDBC/7.0-3.1]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:124)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:388)
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:371)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Transform.call(Transform.java:68)
        at com.marklogic.developer.corb.Transform.call(Transform.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

We tried increasing the thread count and the memory allocation, but to no avail.

My requirement is two fold:

1. What could be the root cause for this? Is there a way to solve the issue?
2. If not, is there a way too trap this exception in the shell script, that is executing the same?

Comment: Anything in the MarkLogic ErrorLog.txt?

Comment: What exactly did you do when you "tried increasing the thread count and the memory allocatgion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible causes. For example it could be JVM garbage collection, a problem on the server, or even something in the network path. Blindly changing things isn't likely to help: first identify the problem, then correct it.

Most often it's the JVM and GC. MarkLogic XCC implements its own keepalive mechanism, something like HTTP 1.1 keepalive. If garbage collection takes too much time this can lead to timeouts and resets. Try monitoring to see if the JVM seems to be running up against its memory allocation and hitting garbage collection frequently, before the error happens. Adding `-verbosegc` may also be useful to detect this. If you think GC is the problem, try adding `-Xincgc`. You may also want to **reduce** the thread count, to reduce memory pressure. You could also increase the allocation with `-Xmx`. But don't do that blindly, and I wouldn't go over 1-GiB.

Definitely check `ErrorLog.txt` and also check the general server health. Is it using any swap space? Is it paging? Anything suspicious in the OS logs? How do the CPU, memory, disk, and network I/O look when the problem occurs?

Every once in a while this kind of thing will turn out to be a firewall or router that doesn't like long-lived connections and shuts them down. If possible arrange it so that your client and server are on the same subnet, with nothing in between except a relatively dumb hub or switch. If there's a local firewall on either host, make sure it won't interfere.

Comment: Garbage collection does not reach out over the network and tell the peer to reset the connection.

Comment: No, but GC causes the JVM to freeze long enough that the connection keepalive times out. Then when the JVM tries to use it again, the server sends a reset because the connection is no longer established.

Comment: That's not true either. Java doesn't send keepalive timers. The TCP stack does, inside the kernel. Ergo freezing the JVM cannot possibly have that effect. Haven't seen a JVM GC freeze for about 18 years either. And you're also asserting that this is 'most often' the cause: do you have some evidence to support that claim?

Comment: Ah, but this Java application does. CorB uses MarkLogic XCC to talk to the server. MarkLogic XCC implements something akin to HTTP 1.1 keepalive, which is different than TCP/IP keepalive. Yes, I have a certain amount of experience with MarkLogic, XCC, and this sort of problem.

Comment: @mblakele ...... I did reduce the allocation to less than 1 GiB...  And also added the option -XX+UseMarkConcSweep: to disable socket pooling . Though I am not receiving any error, but I am not sure if this is the solution to the problem.

Comment: You mean `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` right? Yes, that should help. I'm not sure exactly what the difference is between that and `-Xincgc`, and it may be different in different JVM releases. Anyway the idea is to avoid long GC pauses, which you can monitor using `-verbosegc`. If you see `Connection reset by peer` and monitoring doesn't show long GC pauses, then try the other ideas above.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons for 'connection by peer' are several:

1. The peer application deliberately reset the connection.
2. The peer application closed the connection while there was still unread data in its socket receive buffer.
3. The peer application closed the connection and you kept sending data afterwards.
4. An intermediate firewall dropped the connection, usually because of a timeout.

... and there may be more. The most usual cause is (3), which is an application protocol error on somebody's part.